# PHP Form not processing on submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form displaying via php after no results were displayed in the original query. The form displays fine but when it is submitted it goes to index.php instead of processing using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

```
echo "<form method='post' action='". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>";
echo $error['find'];
echo "<p><label for='find'>Search for Your Favorite Location:</label><br />";
echo "<input type='text' id='find' name='find' value='".($_POST['find'] ? htmlentities($_POST['find']) : '')."' /></p>";
echo "<p><input type='submit' name='submitLocation' value='Submit' /></p></form>";
```

Comment: just leave `action` empty. (But note: If this form is generated within an include Statement on your index.php, you will ofc. recall "index.php")

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not the local file the form is but the URL it opens at, so if it opens at `http://www.mysite.com/index.php` it will lead u back there, like dognose mentions above.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses. The form is not on index.php it is on a "page" in wordpress. Im going to try leaving action blank and see how that works out.

Comment: i've heard years ago that using PHP_SELF is a security lack. you should avoid it. [Informations](http://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that result by leaving `action` empty. I cleaned up the code a bit, and it now looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitLocation'])) 
{
 echo isset($_POST['find']) ? htmlentities($_POST['find']) : '';
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<p><label for='find'>Search for Your Favorite Location:</label><br/>
<input type='text' id='find' name='find' value='' /></p>
<input type='submit' name='submitLocation' value='Submit' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It checks if the form is submitted or not with PHP's [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function. If it was: then it simply echoes the string the user inputted.